# how to select data attribute from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I select an attribute without a value?

Can I avoid using `data-number="value"` to setting or get the attribute in JavaScript?

```js
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
console.log(numberButtons.length)
```

```html
<button data-number>1</button>
<button data-number>2</button>
<button data-number>3</button>
```

I want to get the `NodeList`. This way the `numberButtons` return a empty `NodeList`.

Comment: I added a console.log of the length of the `NodeList` and it correctly outputs 3 for me on Chrome.

Comment: The code snippet is rendering 3, I'm using Opera.

Comment: This is the correct way and uses standard code to do it. I can't imagine that any client made in the last 6 years wouldn't process this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I select an attribute without a value?

The method you are using works:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
```

> Can I avoid using data-number="value" to setting or get the attribute in JavaScript?

Yes. To access the `data-` attribute's value from the node, use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

> I want to get the NodeList. This way the numberButtons return a empty NodeList.

This will return your NodeList:

```
console.log(numberButtons)
```

---

To expand on how `data-` attributes are read:

```js
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
console.log(numberButtons.length)
console.log(
  [...numberButtons].map(i => i.dataset.number)
)
```

```html
<button data-number="1">1</button>
<button data-number="2">2</button>
<button data-number="3">3</button>
```

Notice how `dataset` contains an object, where any attributes line up with a *camelCased* version of whatever you called the attribute, so `data-number` becomes `dataset.number`, and `data-super-number` would become `dataset.superNumber`.

Another thing to keep in mind is when your code is executing, to avoid your JavaScript executing before the DOM is constructed, make sure to wrap your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
    console.log(numberButtons.length)
    console.log(
      [...numberButtons].map(i => i.dataset.number)
    )
})
```

Comment: @Wilker, you are welcome! If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer. Cheers!